# Indian market trading from other countries

Tags: stocks, india

I live in Germany. Is it possible to trade in Indian market from Germany. What if I go to India and come back to Germany, after creating demat and trade account India?

Answer (score 2):

Foreign nationals are not allowed to trade directly in equities. One must be resident Indian or Non Resident Indian to trade in equities. An NRI needs to open a PINS DEMAT account to trade.

Comment: but I've heard that NRI's can trade. Zerodha offers that facility.

Comment: @RajSharma That's what is written in the answer. Non Resident Indian can trade.

Comment: The OP seems to be an NRI from his name. So we can say that he's allowed.

Comment: @Dheer what if someone go to india and open a simple DEMAT account without disclosing that he/shel is an NRI. Is it possible to use trading account from another country then?

Comment: @RajSharma If you open a simple DEMAT as NRI you are violating Regulation. I still don't understand the hesitation in opening a PINS-DEMAT and trading.

Comment: @Dheer because there is brokerage named Zerodha. I hear that they charge more brokerage and transaction fees for NRI's.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are NRI, contact your bank or online brokerage firm to open a DEMAT account for you. They will need it to be linked with your NRE/NRO account.

It is mandatory for NRI's to open NRE/NRO bank account. Once opened, you can trade in certain stocks or funds and also apply for IPO under NRI quota.

Most banks (HDFC, ICICI to name few) will allow you to open NRE/NRO account and DEMAT account without visiting India. You have to submit documents attested by solicitors or Indian High commission.